# Kernel of Möbius transformation

Tags: mobius-transformation

$ f_a = \frac{az + b}{cz +d} $

Would the kernel of this transformation be the scalars of the identity matrix because $ a = d$ & $b=c=0$

so $ \frac{az}d = z$ this leaves us with z or is this wrong.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What do you mean by the kernel of a Möbius transformation? A Möbius transformation has at most one zero, which will be located at $z = -\frac{b}{a}$, assuming $a \neq 0$.

Comment: I have something in my groups and symmetries say to take this as a homomorphism from GL(2,C) to Aut(C). It asks me to find the kernel of it.

Comment: Okay. You should include in your question that what you want to find is the kernel of the homomorphism from $\text{GL}(2, \mathbb{C})$ to $\text{Aut}(\mathbb{C}^{*})$, which will be the set of all scalar multiples of the identity matrix, yes!